# "The test could have ended", "The test is all over" do these 2 sentences mean the same?

Tags: meaning

Consider these 2 sentences

> The test could have ended.
>
> The test is all over.

Do they mean the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't mean the same. One is:

- "The test could have ended", meaning it could have ended but didn't. "Could have [done something]" is a common way to talk about hypothetical situations that never realise.
- "The test is all over", meaning that the test has indeed finished.

Comment: Or that we don't know whether it has ended yet.